# Specific Movie Clip fame rate in Flash/ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am using this code but it is not working correctly.

```
import flash.events.Event;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);

function enterFrame(e:Event):void

{
    var targetFrame:uint = box.currentFrame + 2;

    if(targetFrame > box.totalFrames) targetFrame = 0;

    box.gotoAndStop(50); 
}
```

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you describe what is happening and what you want to happen?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are missing the block statement after an `if`
That means only the next line after an `if` condition will be processed.

It's unclear what is the logics of your code and why the box should stop at frame 50, but here's the code that will make the `targetFrame = 0` and `box.gotoAndStop(50);`:

```
import flash.events.Event;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);

function enterFrame(e:Event):void
{
    var targetFrame:uint = box.currentFrame + 2;

    if(targetFrame > box.totalFrames)
    {
        targetFrame = 0;
        box.gotoAndStop(50);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question wasn't clear. If you need to change the framerate of your movie at runtime you need a different approach. You will basically need to make a timer and change the frame of a movieClip on a tick event.

Comment: can you give me the code for increasing frame rate for my movieClip

Comment: I'm sorry, but I won't be doing your job for you. I've answered you why your code didn't work and explained what you need to do to fix your problem, the rest is up to you.
I will give one more hint - there are more than few questions like this here on this site and some of them have answers for your question. Please do the research.

Answer (score 0):

```
box.gotoAndStop(50);
```

is firing every frame
if you want it to fire when targetFrame > box.totalFrames then use:

```
if(targetFrame > box.totalFrames) 
{
     targetFrame = 0;
     box.gotoAndStop(50);
}
```

But still frame rate for that MovieClip will be the same as stage frame rate. If you want to change frame rate of specific animation you can play it every 2nd frame to reduce fps, if you want increase fps you should skip frame but that will look laggy.

I often use counter variable and put counter++ in onEnterFrame function. For reducing fps:

```
if(counter % 2 == 0)
{
     mc.nextFrame();
}
```

this way if your stage fps is 30, mc fps would be 15 because every 2nd frame counter % 2 == 0

Comment: how to use it I am trying to increase frame tares of my movieClip `box` which is placed on root

Comment: Your method won't work well with looped movieClips as nextFrame() will not start from frame 1 after reaching the last frame. And it's not technically frame rate, it's frame skipping. The animation won't look smoother or faster, especially it will be visible on low frame rates

Answer (score 0):

change 50 to variable targetFrame:

```
import flash.events.Event;
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);

function enterFrame(e:Event):void{
    var targetFrame:uint = box.currentFrame + 2;
    if(targetFrame > box.totalFrames) targetFrame = 0;
    box.gotoAndStop(targetFrame);
}
```